# Python Palindrome Help: Count palindromes in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a program in python that basically tells the user to enter a word and tells them if it's a palindrome or not.

My program:

```
def palindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]

word = input("Enter a word: ")
word2 = word.lower()

if word2 == "":
    print("You failed to input a word")
elif palindrome(word2) == True:
    print(word2,"is a palindrome!")
else:
    print(word2,"is not a palindrome!")
```

I need help modifying my program so that it allows the user to enter a sentence and counts the number of words in the sentence that are palindromes. When I execute the program I would want it to output the palindromes in the sentence.

I've been struggling with this for days and I can't seem to figure out where to start. Help would be much appreciated. Also, I need to MODIFY my program above, not make a completely different program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the string into words then check if each word is a palindrome using a list comp, the length of the list will also give you the count:

```
def palindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]

# split sentence into words and filter out the non palindromes
sentence = [w for w in input("Enter a sentence: ").split() if palindrome(w)]

print(" There are {} palindromes in your sentence\n.".format(len(sentence)))
# print each palindrome from our list
for pal in sentence:
    print("{} is a palindrome".format(pal))
```

If you want to mimic your own code, keep a count as you iterate over the list of words increasing the count if we have a palindrome:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ").split()

count = 0
for w in sentence:
    if palindrome(w):
        count += 1
        print("{} is a palindrome.")
    else:
        print("{}  is not a palindrome.")
print(" There are {} palindromes in your sentence\n.".format(count))
```

To catch single non-letters:

```
def palindrome(word):
    if len(word) > 1:
        return word == word[::-1]
    return word.isalpha()
```

Comment: I think you need add  def palindrome(word):
   return word == word[::-1] if len(word) >1 else None

Comment: @paddu,   that suggests `a`, `i` etc.. are not palindromes, do you have some citation that backs up that?

Comment: Yes, Try the above the code for the value "My sentence has one palindrome - civic" and see the result

Comment: @paddu, then  something like `return  word.isalpha() and word == word[::-1]`, you cannot just ignore all single characters

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. Please do the suitable edit if you get a chance.

Comment: @paddu, I made an edit but this is not a very simple topic, what can and cannot be considered palindromes is probably more for http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for taking time to explain. Much appreciated.